# Under what conditions will bots leave their lane before level 6?

Tags: league-of-legends

In every bot game I've played, the bots will wait until level 6 to leave their lane for ganks.  Today, however, I was surprised by a gank at level 4!  Was this caused by a change in the bot AI, or something else?  We destroyed the tower in our lane extremely early on, is this the reason for the changed behavior?  In general, what are the conditions under which bots will leave their lane before level 6?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The towers definitely make a difference in how the bots react, as they consider their options as they decide what to do, but the most likely answer would be the improve bot AI that Riot released a few months ago, it improved bot play tremendously and probably gives them the capability to gank early if the conditions are right.

Answer (score 2):

You took a turret.  When you take a turret the bots will begin to lane shift as you have unbalanced the threat levels.  Interesting note if you take top/bottom they mostly seem to charge down on the lane that was NOT taken and abandon the pushed lane until you push hard on inner turret.  Not sure why that makes most sense as it usually lets you push it pretty hard for a minute. Not sure if anyone else has any ideas for why they would logically do that.